# Are C++ distributions keep or update parameters on op(URNG, params)?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, c++14

Question to C++ language lawyers, applicable to pretty much any distribution (normal, uniform, poisson, ...), but I'll use Poisson as an example.

Simple code

```
#include <random>

std::default_random_engine rng;

double lambda = 5.0;
std::poisson_distribution<int> Poisson(lambda);

auto A = Poisson(rng);      // call with lambda equal to 5
auto B = Poisson(rng, 3.0); // call with lambda equal to 3
auto C = Poisson(rng);      // call with lambda equal to what?
```

What lambda would be used in case of `C`?

All distribution have the same overloaded operators:

```
template<class URNG> result_type operator()(URNG& g);
template<class URNG> result_type operator()(URNG& g, const param_type& parm);
```

If we construct distribution with one set of parameteres, then call second `op()`, will distribution state altered? Or it will use parameters from the constructor?

Comment: "*What lambda would be used in case of C?*" Why would it not do the same thing as `A`?

Comment: @NicolBolas because it might be changed in `B`, i guess

Comment: What is the meaning of your title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 3.0 is not saved.  `C` will use 5.0.  This is specified in the Random number distribution requirements table for *all* distributions.

Comment: Looks like it. Just read Table 118 of C++ std (n4296), and you're right, wish it was expressed a bit more clear